# How to type a context and a canvas in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this right now

```
const canvas: any = canvasRef.current;
const context : any = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

I have given them any values.

Apparently theres is a context type.

```
https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/modules/_node_modules__types_node_vm_d_._vm_.html
```

But is it the one i need?

Nonetheless , i dont know how to type canvas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canvas itself is a `HTMLCanvasElement`, and the context is a `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

```
const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = canvas.getContext('2d')!;
```

Note that the [`getContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) method has return type `RenderingContext2D | null`, so the `!` is needed here to assert that the result is not `null`. (Or you can check for `null` and handle that case.)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGYBu8IC4YAkAqBZAMgMKIoQCiANgKYC2VYsAvDACYjACudDAdMAE5V4UKpVr0oACgDkCZKmkBKANwBYAFChIsYFAAeGYvIgAleiyr8AlmADmhcCL1QATABEYzOaR62qUBwYqZxkXFiUAQjV1IA)

Comment: Seems to work thanks. Althought I had to use the ! with canvas too.
````const canvas: HTMLCanvasElement  = canvasRef.current!;````

Comment: That will depend on what `canvasRef` is; if it could be `null` or `undefined` then you'll want to handle that.